# ElasticSearch Terms Aggregation not working with custom Analyzer and Pattern Tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am trying the Terms Aggregation for the first time and there seems to be an issue with the custom pattern tokenizer I am using.

Here is the Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "contentItemType": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer"
      },
      "theme": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "patternAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "patternTokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "patternTokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ";"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I am trying to search with the aggregation API http://my_server/index_name/_search here is the result:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_contentItemType": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Correspondence; Reports",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "Correspondence",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Meeting Minutes; Administrative Records; Reports",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Correspondence; Legal and Treaty Material; Reports",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Correspondence; Memoranda",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Memoranda",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Reports",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "group_by_theme": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "International Relations",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Key Events; Dissent; Dissent; Resistance; Human Rights",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Border Security and Migration; Key Events",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Border Security and Migration; Second World War Aftermath",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Domestic Politics",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Domestic Politics; Border Security and Migration",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Economics and Trade; International Relations",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Embassy and Consulate Administration; Industry and Agriculture; International Relations",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Populations and Social Policy; Second World War Aftermath; International Relations",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the issue with the aggregation. I have been stuck on this problem for quite a few days. I have seen so many examples and all but still not able to solve this issue.
Please help. Thanks in Advance!!!

**EDIT!!!**
Here is the full mapping after @CatalinM answer:

```
{
    "local_cwee": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
                "author": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "commentaries": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "contentDateEndMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "contentDateEndSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "contentDateEndYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "contentDateMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "contentDateMonthSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "contentDateStartMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "contentDateStartSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "contentDateStartYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "contentDateYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "contentDoi": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "contentItemType": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "contentItemTypeFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "contentTitle": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "copyrightNotices": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "imageName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "text": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "countries": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "country": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "coverDateEndMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "coverDateEndSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "coverDateEndYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "coverDateMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "coverDateMonthSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "coverDateStartMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "coverDateStartSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "coverDateStartYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "coverDateYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "displayName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "documentDoi": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "documentLevel": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },                
                "keyEvents": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "language": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "languageFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "languages": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "languagesFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "moduleNumber": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "notes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "pageTranscript": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "whiteSpaceAnalyzer"
                },
                "people": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "publicationDate": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDateEndMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDateEndSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "publicationDateEndYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDateMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDateMonthSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "publicationDateStartMonth": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDateStartSpecified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "publicationDateStartYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDateYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publicationDoi": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "publicationId": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "publicationIdFacet": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "publicationTitle": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "publicationType": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "publicationTypeFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "publicationYear": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "publisherName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "publisherNameFacet": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                }
                "subject": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subjectAreas": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subjectAreasFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subjectCountries": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subjectCountriesFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subjectKeyword": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subjectKeywordFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subthemeFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "subthemes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "theme": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "themeFacets": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "themes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer",
                    "fielddata": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with aggegation

Comment: @opsterESNinja, In the result, you can see that in contentType Bucket the same key e.g. "Correspondance" is coming with other keys. I should have given the seperate results for all the keys.So the count for "Correspondance" key in contentType Bucket should have been 7

Comment: terms works only on keyword field AFAIK analyzers dont apply for keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your custom tokenizer, the tokens in the text field are "Correspondence", "Meeting Minutes", "Administrative Records", ..etc. So i don't think you need the keyword field.

To make aggregations work on the text field, you'll have to add `"fielddata": true` in the mapping. This is by default disabled because aggregations on large text fields are not wanted, but in your case the tokens are exactly the values you want to aggregate on.

here's the simplified configuration

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "contentItemType": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "analyzer": "patternAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "patternAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "patternTokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "patternTokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ";"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the query:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
      "test" : {
          "terms" : { "field" : "contentItemType" }
      }
  }
}
```

and result:

```
"aggregations": {
    "test": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": " Administrative Records",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "Meeting Minutes",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": " Reports",
                "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @CatalinM, I tried the method that you posted.. now the aggregation buckets are coming empty when I am running the query.. I have removed ```"fields": {"keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }``` and added ```"fielddata" : true``` instead. Please tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Here is the example of the document ```{
 "_index": "local_cwee",
 "_type": "_doc",
 "_id": "someId",
 "_score": 1.0,
 "_source": {
  "theme": "Key Events; Dissent; Dissent; Resistance; Human Rights",
  "themeFacets": "ah",
  "contentItemType": "Meeting Minutes; Administrative Records; Reports",
  "contentItemTypeFacets": "ae aa ak"
  }
} ```

Comment: i don't think it's from the data, it works also with these values. Can you put the mapping: {HOST}/local_cwee/_mapping and the query ( if it;s different from what i sent ) ? also, what version of ES do you use ?

Comment: I have added the Mapping in the question as edit. The ES version is 7.3.0.

Comment: It's working also on 7.3.0 with your mapping. I assume that you defined custom analyzer whiteSpaceAnalyzer and missing comma before "subject" field it's a typo when you posted.

Comment: not sure why it's not working on your side. Maybe start testing with a new index, with a simple mapping and insert few docs. This is what i inserted for test: {
  "contentItemType": "Meeting Minutes; Administrative Records; Reports",
  "theme": "Key Events; Dissent; Dissent; Resistance; Human Rights"
}

Comment: Thanks @CatalinM.. The query that I was using was wrong.. Other things were fine and now it is separating as expected.